# Is the unit sphere of $C[0,1]$ connected?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, connectedness

Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$.

The induced norm of $C[0,1]$ is supremum norm, i.e
$$\|f\|= \sup_{x\in[0,1]} f(x) .$$
Under this norm, $C[0,1]$ is a Banach space. Moreover, it is a Banach algebra with the multiplication being usual multiplication.

My question is whether $S^1$, the unit sphere of $C[0,1]$, is connected or not.

Comment: If $g$ is in the unit sphere, then there is $x_0\in[0,1]$ such that $|g(x_0)|=1$. Let $f(x)=g(x_0)$ and take $g_t(x)=(1-t)g(x)+tf(x)$. That connects $g$ and $f$. Finally, $h_t(x)=e^{2\pi i t}f(x)$, connects $f$ and the constant function $1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is path-connected, like the unit spheres of every normed (real or complex) space except $\Bbb R$: if $g\ne -f$, consider $\gamma(t)=\frac{tf+(1-t)g}{\lVert tf+(1-t)g\rVert_\infty}$. This is well defined because with these hypothesis $tf+(1-t)g=0$ for some $t\in[0,1]$ if and only if $g=-f$ and $t=\frac12$. If $g=-f$, make a path from $f$ to a third function $h$ (here you use $\dim_{\Bbb R} V>1$) and then one from $h$ to $g$.

Comment: Can we use this proof for the general case? I mean, how about the connectedness of unit circle of an arbitrary Banach algebra?

Comment: @VuLinh Yes, that's what I said. This works for all normed $\Bbb C$-vector spaces and for all normed $\Bbb R$-vector spaces except $\Bbb R$.